# Nombres en vez de id en CRUD de Angular con PHP y Msql

Tags: php, html, mysql, angular, typescript

Estoy teniendo problemas con una CRUD de Angular,PHP y Mysql no e logrado que me liste los nombres de ciertas tablas en vez de los id que puedo implementar para esto?.
Aca dejo una pequeña parte de codigo que uso para listar y actualizar. Dejo este codigo e imagenes que hasta ese punto me sale bien pero sin el nombre y solo los ids si necesitan mas información con mucho gusto la suministrare.

Porfa ayuda

vehiculo.component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="personaA" class="mat-elevation-z8" style="width:
100%;">
<ng-container matColumnDef="idPersona">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>N°</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let persona"> {{persona.idPersona}} </td>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="idTipoPersona">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Tipo Persona</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let persona"> {{persona.idTipoPersona}} </td>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="primerNombre">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Primer Nombre</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let persona"> {{persona.primerNombre}} </td>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="editar">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Editar</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let persona">
        <a mat-icon-button [routerLink]="['editar', persona.idPersona]">
            <mat-icon color="primary">edit</mat-icon>
        </a>
    </td>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="eliminar">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Eliminar</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let persona">
        <button mat-icon-button>
     
            <mat-icon color="warn"(click)="eliminarPersona(persona)" >delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </td>
</ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['idPersona', 'idTipoPersona', 'primerNombre', 'editar', 'eliminar']">
</tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let fila; columns: ['idPersona', 'idTipoPersona', 'primerNombre', 'editar', 'eliminar'];">
</tr>
```

vehiculo.componet.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { DialogoConfirmacionComponent } from '../dialogo-confirmacion/dialogo-confirmacion.component';
import { AcmeserviceService } from '../services/acmeservice.service';
import { Persona } from '../shared/acmebs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-persona',
  templateUrl: './persona.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./persona.component.css']
})
export class PersonaComponent implements OnInit {

  public personaA: Persona[] = [
    new Persona("", "", undefined)
  ];

  constructor(private acmeService: AcmeserviceService, private dialogo: MatDialog, private snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  eliminarPersona(persona: Persona) {
    this.dialogo
      .open(DialogoConfirmacionComponent, {
        data: `¿Realmente quieres eliminar a ${persona.primerNombre}?`
      })
      .afterClosed()
      .subscribe((confirmado: Boolean) => {
        if (!confirmado) return;
        this.acmeService
          .deletePersona(persona)
          .subscribe(() => {
            this.obtenerPersonas();
            this.snackBar.open('Persona eliminada', undefined, {
              duration: 1500,
            });
          });
      })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.obtenerPersonas();
  }

  obtenerPersonas() {
    return this.acmeService
      .getPersonas()
      .subscribe((persona: Persona[]) => {
        this.personaA = persona        
      }
        );
  }

}
```

Base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Clases.ts

```
export class Persona {
    constructor(
        public idTipoPersona: any,
        public primerNombre: any,
        public idPersona?: number,
    ) { }

}
export class tipopersona {
    constructor(
        public tipoPersona: string,
        public idTipoPersona?: number,
    ) { }

}
```

La tabla listada mostrando id

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

acmeservice.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Color, Marca, Persona, tipopersona, TipoVehiculo, Vehiculo } from '../shared/acmebs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AcmeserviceService {

  baseUrl = environment.baseUrl
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

//////////////////////////////////////////////TIPO PERSONA////////////////////////////////////////////////////
getTiposPersonas() {
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}TipoPersona/selectAll.php`);
}

getTipoPersona(id: string | number) {
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}TipoPersona/select.php?idTipoPersona=${id}`);
}

addTipoPersona(tipopersona: tipopersona) {
  console.log(tipopersona);
  
  return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}TipoPersona/insert.php`, tipopersona);
}

deleteTipoPersona(tipopersona: tipopersona) {
  return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}TipoPersona/delete.php?idTipoPersona=${tipopersona.idTipoPersona}`);
}

updateTipoPersona(tipopersona: tipopersona) {
  console.log(tipopersona);
  
  return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}TipoPersona/update.php`, tipopersona);
}

 //////////////////////////////////////////////PERSONA////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 getPersonas() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}Persona/selectAll.php`);
  }

  getPersona(id: string | number) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}Persona/select.php?idPersona=${id}`);
  }

  addPersona(persona: Persona) {    
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}Persona/insert.php`, persona);
  }

  deletePersona(persona: Persona) {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}Persona/delete.php?idPersona=${persona.idPersona}`);
  }

  updatePersona(persona: Persona) {    
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}Persona/update.php`, persona);
  }
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Aca ya empieza los componentes de update

personaeditar.component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #formTipoPersona="ngForm">
    <p>
        <input matInput name="idTipoPersona" [(ngModel)]="persona.idTipoPersona" type="any" placeholder="Tipo de Persona">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input matInput name="primerNombre" [(ngModel)]="persona.primerNombre" type="any" placeholder="Primer Nombre">
    </p>
    <p>
        <button type="submit" mat-flat-button color="accent">Guardar</button> &nbsp;
        <button (click)="volver()" type="button" mat-flat-button color="primary">Volver</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

personaeditar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AcmeserviceService } from '../services/acmeservice.service';
import { Persona } from '../shared/acmebs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-personaeditar',
  templateUrl: './personaeditar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./personaeditar.component.css']
})
export class PersonaeditarComponent implements OnInit {

  public persona: Persona = new Persona( "", "", undefined );

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,private router: Router,
              private acmeService: AcmeserviceService,private snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let idPersona = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    this.acmeService.getPersona(idPersona).subscribe((persona_: Persona) => {
      this.persona = persona_
    });
  }

  volver() {
    this.router.navigate(['persona']);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.acmeService.updatePersona(this.persona).subscribe(() => {
      this.snackBar.open('Persona actualizada', undefined, {
        duration: 1500,
      });
      this.volver();
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: No estás incluyendo el `tipoPersona` en las columnas de la tabla. La columna se llama `Tipo Persona` pero el valor que tiene es `idTipoPersona`.

Comment: Entonces la corrección hay que hacerla en el back y que el JSON contenga toda la información necesaria. Deberías replantear la pregunta porque el problema no es de front.

Comment: @Lobos Trataré de explicarte acá como funciona el back manda toda la información hasta el front el front lo recibe por medio de el acmeservicio.ts y de ahí ya uno pide los datos en los componentes osea si pido los datos de la tabla TIPOPERSONA me llega los siguiente `idTipoPersona=1/tipoPersona=Conductor`es un ejemplo y en la tabla PERSONA si la pido me llega esto `idPersona=1/idTipoPersona=1/primerNombre=Felipe` ejemplo si me entiendes? Osea las tablas Persona y tipoPersona están relacionadas en la base de datos

Comment: @Lobos por cierto si gustas grabo un vídeo y me muestro y explico que es lo que quiero conseguir si gustas

Comment: @Lobos aca te dejo el link [video exlicativo](https://youtu.be/B9qk9TrL-RA)

Comment: Las bases de datos estan relacionadas, pero a la hora de hacer la consulta te esta devolviendo la tabla con el id, no con los datos que resultan de un `inner join` si no me equivoco ( o `left join`). Este trabajo se hace en el back, como dice @Lobos. Debes cambiar tus consultas y tus clases tambien, pues en vez de tener un tipo number en la clase persona (idTipoPersona), deberia ser un objeto y trabajar en front de manera más natural (con los objetos)